# How to expand several arguments in an environment?

Tags: environments, expansion, optional-arguments

I have an environment that I've defined as follows:

```
\newenvironment{regularEnumerateEx}[2][0em]
  {begin{listSkeleton}[#1]{enumerate}{#2}}
  {\end{listSkeleton}}
```

The problem is that I need to expand `#2` before passing it to `listSkeleton`. It's okay if `#1` is expanded (I think). I know I have to use `\expandafter` in some way, but not exactly how.

Comment: Do you need to expand it only once or completely?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I'm not familiar enough with LaTeX to comment on that. If expanding it completely is easier and doesn't break anything, then that will suffice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is OK to expand it completely, not just once you can use `\edef` with a temporary macro:

```
\newenvironment{regularEnumerateEx}[2][0em]{%
  \edef\temp{%
    \noexpand\begin{listSkeleton}[#1]{enumerate}{#2}%
  }%
  \temp
}{%
  \end{listSkeleton}%
}
```

If you really only want to expand it once you can do:

```
\newenvironment{regularEnumerateEx}[2][0em]{%
  \def\temp{\begin{listSkeleton}[#1]{enumerate}}%
  \expandafter\temp\expandafter{#2}%
}{%
  \end{listSkeleton}%
}
```

---

Often the macro `\@tempa` is used for such temparary assignments, but in user documents it requires `\makeatletter ... \makatother` around the code. So for simplicity I just used `\temp`. It is anyway just used inside a group.

Comment: In the first code there is a `\noexpand` missing, right before `\begin`. Otherwise the `\edef` will not work.

Comment: @Axel: Yes, indeed. I overlooked that. Fixed now.