# Problem with expand, all restatable theorems points to the same theorem

Tags: theorems, expansion

I'm trying to manually do a small script that let me put proofs at the end, restate theorem... But I'm having some troubles with the restate, because all the theorems have the same name, so when I want to restate them at the end all of them have the same name. Indeed, I wrote in a function:

```
\edef\namerestate{prAtEndRestate\roman{counterAllProofEnd}}
\begin{restatable}{#2}{\namerestate}\label{thm:prAtEnd\thecounterAllProofEnd}
    #4
\end{restatable}
```

and in my code:

```
\prAtEndRestatei*
\prAtEndRestateii*
```

But the two theorems that are displayed are exactly the same (the last theorem written)!

Any idea what's going wrong?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, thm-restate}
\usepackage{thmtools} %%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\providecommand*\thmautorefname{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\providecommand*\corollaryautorefname{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\providecommand*\lemmaautorefname{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Manual theorems}
\edef\namerestate{manualtheoremi}
\begin{restatable}{thm}{\namerestate}
  My first manual theorem
\end{restatable}

\edef\namerestate{manualtheoremii}
\begin{restatable}{thm}{\namerestate}
  My second manual theorem
\end{restatable}

Restitution:
\manualtheoremi*
\manualtheoremii*

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
This appears to work, but please let me know if there is a better way, especially if xparse/latex3e proposed better solutions: [How to expand several arguments in an environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/how-to-expand-several-arguments-in-an-environment)

Answer (score 2):

## Simple LaTeX3-based solution

Here is a simple solution using LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\providecommand*\thmautorefname{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_tobias_thm_counter_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobias_declare_thm_label:nn #1#2
{
  \label { thm #1 prAtEnd #2 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_declare_thm_label:nn { xn }

% #1: theorem type
% #2: unique suffix for theorem (e.g., counter representation as roman numerals)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nn #1#2
{
  % Start 'restatable' environment
  \restatable {#1} { restatableThm #2 }
  % Write the \label command with the appropriate label based on #2
  \tobias_declare_thm_label:xn
    { \char_generate:nn { `\: } { 12 } } % colon with catcode 12 (other)
    {#2}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nn { nx }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { proclaimRestatable } { m }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tobias_thm_counter_int % increment the counter
    % Start 'restatable' environment
    \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nx
      {#1}
      { \int_to_roman:n \g_tobias_thm_counter_int }
  }
  { \endrestatable }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{proclaimRestatable}{thm}
  My first theorem
\end{proclaimRestatable}

\begin{proclaimRestatable}{thm}
  My second theorem
\end{proclaimRestatable}

Restitution:
\restatableThmi*
\restatableThmii*

Reference to \autoref{thm:prAtEndi}.\par
Reference to \autoref{thm:prAtEndii}.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of result]

This terminates the simpler LaTeX3-based solution I found. Here follows the first solution I came up with. It was a bit more complicated; I'm leaving it here in case you find the technique and explanations useful.

## Other (more convoluted) LaTeX3-based solution

The trickiest part for me in this first solution was to produce the theorem labels you wanted with correct category codes, because in LaTeX3 syntax (after specifying `\ExplSyntaxOn`), the category code of a colon `:` is *letter* (11), whereas in LaTeX2e syntax (in particular, in your document body), it is *other* (12).<sup>a</sup> In order to do this, I used a token list variable (`\l__tobias_thm_label_tl`) that is assembled bits by bits using `\tl_put_right:Nx` and `\tl_put_right:Nn`, and passed it as a *value argument* (`V`) to a macro that expands to `\label {#1}` (`#1` being replaced by the *value* of the token list variable).

Actually, writing the `\label{thm:prAtEnd...}` with a `:` of category code 11 *(letter)* seems to work as well—but not with category code 10 or 13, for instance. I suppose this is because writing a `:` of category code 11 or 12 to the `.aux` file produces the *same result* (excerpt from my `.aux` file):

```
\newlabel{thm:prAtEndi}{{1.1}{1}{Some section}{thm.1.1}{}}
```

Therefore, when the `.aux` file is read back, it makes no difference whether the `:` character tokens in the label were passed to `\label` with category code 11 or 12. Still, I think it is cleaner to keep the logic that passes `\label` an argument with exactly the same category codes as would be obtained for a `\label` written after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\providecommand*\thmautorefname{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_tobias_thm_counter_int
\tl_new:N \l__tobias_thm_label_tl

% #1: unique suffix for theorem (e.g., counter representation as roman numerals)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobias_make_thm_label_name:n #1
{
  % Start of label: three tokens
  \tl_set:Nn \l__tobias_thm_label_tl { thm }
  % Append a colon of category 12 (other)
  % [unlike normal colons under \ExplSyntaxOn regime]
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__tobias_thm_label_tl { \char_generate:nn { `\: } { 12 } }
  % End of label
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__tobias_thm_label_tl { prAtEnd #1 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobias_declare_thm_label:n #1
{
  \label {#1}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_declare_thm_label:n { V }

% #1: theorem type
% #2: unique suffix for theorem (e.g., counter representation as roman numerals)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nn #1#2
{
  % Assemble and store the label name with correct category codes inside
  % token list variable \l__tobias_thm_label_tl.
  \tobias_make_thm_label_name:n {#2}
  % Start 'restatable' environment
  \restatable {#1} { restatableThm #2 }
  % Write the \label command with the appropriate label based on #2
  \tobias_declare_thm_label:V \l__tobias_thm_label_tl
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nn { nx }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { proclaimRestatable } { m }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tobias_thm_counter_int % increment the counter
    % Start 'restatable' environment
    \tobias_start_proclaim_thm:nx
      {#1}
      { \int_to_roman:n \g_tobias_thm_counter_int }
  }
  { \endrestatable }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{proclaimRestatable}{thm}
  My first theorem
\end{proclaimRestatable}

\begin{proclaimRestatable}{thm}
  My second theorem
\end{proclaimRestatable}

Restitution:
\restatableThmi*
\restatableThmii*

Reference to \autoref{thm:prAtEndi}.\par
Reference to \autoref{thm:prAtEndii}.
\end{document}
```

---

**Footnote**

a. Note that in French documents, the colon `:` typically has category code 13 *(active)* in order to produce the desired spacing. For this reason, I generally don't use it in labels (avoiding potential problems...).

Comment: I found a simpler solution and edited my post. If it doesn't do what you wanted, please explain precisely why.